# I am editing a model to be 3D printed, how to merge two faces in a same object?

Tags: faces

I have a model like this:

[image]

[image]

Due to overhang issue I would like it modified from this:

[image]

To this **(edited in GIMP)**:

[image]

My idea is to:

1. Extrude the leftmost and the bottommost faces until they are intersected (done, as you can see in the two bottommost screenshot above)
2. **Join two faces (I still don't know how to do this!)**
3. From the joined edges fill them with faces
4. Delete unnecessary faces and edges

From Google search I came with Intersect (Knife) and Intersect (Boolean). I have selected the two faces, then choose either of them, and my model was gone from Blender.

So... how can I join two (or more) intersected faces in Blender, within the same object?

Comment: if i know your question, you can use boolean union to merge two mesh part into one,
but you can simply join the object (ctrl-J) this is non-destructive way the mesh will sliced as intended on slicer as long both mesh is manifold

Answer (score 0):

If your mesh is not pathological in some other way, (duplicate vertices, inconsistent normals, or somesuch), *Intersect Knife* *should* work, to create an edge at the intersection of your faces.

However, if the angles are convenient, then you can avoid the calculation of intersections by just snapping the ends of your faces together.

With Snap set to 'To: Vertex', and 'With: Active', <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> the bottom edge of the vertical face to the horizontal one, and then <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, vice-versa:

[image]

If you have *Automerge* switched on in Header > Options, you're done.

Or you can manually weld: <kbd>M</kbd> Merge > By Distance.